# PyMC3 sample function

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I am using a CAR model as in https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/PyMC3_tips_and_heuristic.html. I am using the same problem and model described in the link: Oi∼exp(Poisson(exp(β0+β1∗aff+ϕi+log(Ei))), in which I want to obtain the values of β0 and β1.

Here, model2 operates the parameters:

```
with pm.Model() as model2:
    # Vague prior on intercept
    beta0 = pm.Normal('beta0', mu=0.0, tau=1.0e-5)
    # Vague prior on covariate effect
    beta1 = pm.Normal('beta1', mu=0.0, tau=1.0e-5)

    # Random effects (hierarchial) prior
    tau_h = pm.Gamma('tau_h', alpha=3.2761, beta=1.81)
    # Spatial clustering prior
    tau_c = pm.Gamma('tau_c', alpha=1.0, beta=1.0)

     # Regional random effects
    theta = pm.Normal('theta', mu=0.0, tau=tau_h, shape=N)
    mu_phi = CAR2('mu_phi', w=wmat2, a=amat2, tau=tau_c, shape=N)

    # Zero-centre phi
    phi = pm.Deterministic('phi', mu_phi-tt.mean(mu_phi))

    # Mean model
    mu = pm.Deterministic('mu', tt.exp(logE + beta0 + beta1*quil + theta + phi))

    # Likelihood
    Yi = pm.Poisson('Yi', mu=mu, observed=O)

    # Marginal SD of heterogeniety effects
    sd_h = pm.Deterministic('sd_h', tt.std(theta))
    # Marginal SD of clustering (spatial) effects
    sd_c = pm.Deterministic('sd_c', tt.std(phi))
    # Proportion sptial variance
    alpha = pm.Deterministic('alpha', sd_c/(sd_h+sd_c))

    trace2 = pm.sample(1000, tune=500, cores=4,
                   init='advi',
                   nuts_kwargs={"target_accept":0.9,
                                "max_treedepth": 15})
```

My question is: when using the sample function, with 4000 iterations (1000 per core), I obtain a vector of 4000 positions for each parameter in the model. What is the best value for the parameter: the last value (result of the final iteration) or the average value, since they are calculated via a Markov chain?

Comment: Last sample is arbitrary - that's basically the equivalent of picking one at random. What do you plan to do with a point estimate (mean or otherwise)? If reporting, then the interval of highest posterior density is usually preferred; if predicting, then one instead uses all the samples through a posterior predictive sampling strategy.